# how to store scan data in 1 variable and pass it to other activity using Zxing liberary

Tags: android, android-activity, qr-code, zxing

I have integrated scanner through zxing Liberary.I want when scanner scan Qr code So scan data store in 1 variable and this scan data  than pass to another activity.how this will be please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bundle for this.
Do you have only primitive values to pass ?
Otherwise you have do serialization and pass.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the Scan using Intent Integration, you should have implemented onActivityResult(..., Intent i)

i holds the Data from the QR Code and you can get it by calling i.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")